# Sort and Filter columns created dynamically in ngTable

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

In this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/weigBKLuiTKp9vY7YRCE?p=preview) I have an ngTable with columns created dynamically. The columns are sortable and filterable, however when clicking on the title the sort doesn't work and the filter doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,NgTableParams) {

   $scope.cols = [ 
        {nm:'uid', title:'User ID', sortable: 'uid', filter:{uid: 'text'}}, 
        {nm:'ugr', title: 'Group ID', sortable: 'ugr',filter:{ugr: 'text'}} 
      ];


      $scope.data = [ 
        { uid: 'aaa',ugr: '222'},
        { uid: 'bbb', ugr: '111'}
      ];

      $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({dataset: $scope.data});

});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCtl" ng-app="app">

  <table ng-table-dynamic="tableParams with cols" show-filter="true" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
      <td ng-repeat="col in cols">{{row[col.nm]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: see this http://ng-table.com/#/sorting/demo-sorting-basic

Comment: this doesn't help me as in the demo the columns are not created dynamically

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Add references to AngularJS. EG:

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>

2)Add references to ngTable's javascript and css files. EG:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/v1.0.0/dist/ng-table.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/v1.0.0/dist/ng-table.js"></script>

3)Where you declare your app module, add ngTable:

angular.module("myApp", ["ngTable"]);

4)In your html file within the controller where you plan to use ng-table, add:

<table ng-table="vm.tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
            {{user.name}}</td>
        <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
            {{user.age}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

5)In your javascript file within the controller where you plan to use ng-table, declare:

var self = this;
var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50} /*,*/];
self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: data});
```

demo [enter link description here](http://ng-table.com/#/)

Comment: this doesn't help, as in the question the columns are created dynamically